# How to perform image segmentation on 4-band geotiff using Python's scikit-image?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scikit-image, geotiff

I am attempting to read a 4-band (red, green, blue, near-infrared) geotiff ([example data](ftp://dataworks.library.unr.edu/naip/2010/quarter_quad/41117/)) and perform a [quickshift segmentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.quickshift) using the `scikit-image` module in Python.

I have created the following script (based on the [scikit example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_segmentations.html#quickshift-image-segmentation)):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from skimage.segmentation import felzenszwalb, slic, quickshift
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
from skimage.util import img_as_float

image = r'C:\path\to\my\geotiff.tif'
img = io.imread(image, as_grey=False, plugin="gdal")
segments_quick = quickshift(img, kernel_size=3, max_dist=6, ratio=0.5)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: the input array must be have a shape == (.., ..,[ ..,] 3)), got (4, 436, 553)
```

I am pretty sure the numpy array needs to be reshaped somehow.  How can I properly read the multiband geotiff into a numpy array and perform the image segmentation?

Comment: Maybe try `image = plt.imread('C:\path\to\my\geotiff.tif');`

Comment: @I'L'I I get the following error when using that approach: `ValueError: the input array must be have a shape == (.., ..,[ ..,] 3)), got (436, 553, 4)`

Comment: There is another way you could try with the import statement: `from skimage import io; io.use_plugin('matplotlib')`- see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343517/scikit-learn-valueerror-can-not-convert-object-to-float64), or perhaps try `pil` instead of `plt`. Otherwise you could probably use `numpy.reshape` to get the correct array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is that `quickshift()` thinks your image is `rgb`.  I downloaded a random image from the link you provided and read it into skimage.

```
img = io.imread('./m_4111722_ne_11_1_20100704.tif')
```

I resized it to 128x128x4 (to make computation easy)

```
img = transform.resize(img, (128, 128, 4))
```

then ran `quickshift()`

```
segments = quickshift(img, kernel_size=3, max_dist=6, ratio=0.5)
```

and got the same error.

```
ValueError: the input array must be have a shape == (.., ..,[ ..,] 3)), got (128, 128, 4)
```

Higher up in the stack trace it says

```
skimage/segmentation/_quickshift.pyx inskimage.segmentation._quickshift.\
quickshift (skimage/segmentation/_quickshift.c:1710)()

/****/****/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/color/colorconv.pyc in rgb2lab(rgb)
    901     This function uses rgb2xyz and xyz2lab.
    902     """
--> 903     return xyz2lab(rgb2xyz(rgb))
```

So you can see `_quickshift.pyx` is trying to convert `rgb --> xyz` and then `xyz --> lab`.  So its *assuming* your image is `rgb`.  The [skimage docs](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.quickshift) for `quickshift()` shows it has a flag `convert2lab` that defaults to `True`.

> **convert2lab** : bool, optional (default True) Whether the input should be converted to Lab colorspace prior to segmentation. For this purpose, the input is *assumed to be RGB*.

If I re-run your function with that flag set to `False`

```
segments = quickshift(img, kernel_size=3, convert2lab=False, max_dist=6, ratio=0.5)
```

it runs.

```
plt.imshow(segments);
```

[image]

**Edit**:

Just as an aside, I noticed your image shape is `(4, 436, 553)` which is also problematic.  `skimage` expects the color channel to be last.  This can be remedied with

```
img = img.transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks! Interestingly, transposing the array does not seem to help in my case.  The results appear distorted (y-scale is unusually small) when I plot them after the transpose operation.

Comment: Hmmm.  Not sure why that would be.  Only thing I can think of is I didn't have `gdal` in my analysis.  I'll download it this weekend and play around with it and then I'll get back to ya.

Answer (score 0):

2 crucial lines from the example in your linked page,

```
from skimage.util import img_as_float
img = img_as_float(image[::2, ::2])
```

That is, you are correct. You do need to convert your image to another format. Convert it using img_as_float().

Comment: When I run `img = img_as_float(image)` I get the following error: `ValueError: can not convert |S45 to float64`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry that that didn't work. You may want to check out http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.external.tifffile.html